# SweetAlert 2 and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sweetalert2

So basically we are using SweetAlert2 on our website.
Everything is running well on various web browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge except Internet Explorer.

At first - as almost everyone know - SweetAlert2 is using arrow functions which are not supported by Internet Explorer. However, as we also know - the Internet Explorer is not supporting arrow functions so we decided to overwrite arrow function with classic function.

From:

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Success',
    html: message,
    icon: 'success'
    }).then((result) => {
        window.location.reload();
});
```

We get to this:

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Success',
    html: message,
    icon: 'success'
    }).then(function (result) {
        window.location.reload();
});
```

And yes, the code from above make it works on Internet Explorer. We were happy until we realise that this kind of code also results in problems with AJAX POST requests so almost all functions in the application stopped to work.

Otherwise - if we switch back to arrow functions in SweetAlert2 call method - then all of our ajax post requests are working without any problems.

**@edit => More information about scenario**

So after the ajax call - the post data is beeing send to the php file which checks if post data has been sent by using isset() method. If so then it makes query to the database, elseway it returns error code.

In scenario when we use arrow functions - isset() checking post data returns true and there is a query.

In scenario when we dont use arrow function - isset() checking post data returns false and the ajax call is returning errorcode.

*So it looks like the post data from the form is not beeing send.*

**@edit2 - adding js function code in the link below**

```
$('.form-ajax').on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr('action');
    var redirect = false;
    var callback = false;

    // Sweet Ajax
    var confirm_question = false;
    var success_msg = false;

    if ($(this).attr('redirect')    !== undefined)      { redirect = $(this).attr('redirect'); }
    if ($(this).attr('callback')    !== undefined)      { callback = $(this).attr('callback'); }

    // Sweet Ajax
    if ($(this).attr('confirm')         !== undefined) { confirm_question = $(this).attr('confirm'); }
    if ($(this).attr('success')         !== undefined) { success_msg = $(this).attr('success'); }


    if (confirm_question !== false) {

        // Pytanie zostało określone
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Potwierdzenie',
            html: confirm_question,
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Potwierdź',
            cancelButtonText: 'Anuluj'
            }).then(function (result) {
            if (result.value) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: link,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(result) {

                        if (result == 'ok') {

                            var komunikat = 'Operacja została wykonana poprawnie.';

                            Swal.fire({
                                title: 'Sukces',
                                html: komunikat,
                                icon: 'success'
                            }).then(function (result) {
                                if (redirect) {
                                    window.location.replace(redirect);
                                } else {
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                            });

                        } else {

                            if (result == '405') {

                                if (callback) {
                                    $('#' + callback).html('<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Wystąpił błąd1. Odśwież stronę i spróbuj ponownie.');
                                } else {

                                    // swal fire
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        title: 'Błąd',
                                        html: 'Wystąpił błąd. Odśwież stronę i spróbuj ponownie.',
                                        icon: 'error'
                                    });

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

});
```

Above function returns "Wystąpił błąd1. Odśwież stronę i spróbuj ponownie." if we are not using arrow functions which means that result is returning 405.

We are stuck and dont know what else we can try?

Comment: I don't see how the above change would stop ajax code from working?

Comment: @ChrisG after ajax request from js - the php file is checking if $post['name'] is isset and if it is not isset then it returns error code, elseway it does query to the database. When arrow functions are used - the check returns true elseway it returns false so the whole ajax call error code.

Comment: Can you add the relevant ajax code to the question? I still don't see how the two could possibly be related but we need to see the ajax code to debug it.

Comment: @ChrisG sure, just added the code

Comment: That's a wall of code. Please create a [mre].

Comment: @ChrisG i've updated the code and deleted the part which is not actually running.

Comment: What are the `redirect`, `confirm` attributes? I don't know what they are so I tested without them and postback some simple data and it can work well in IE. It can go into the `result == 'ok'`. In your scenario, it goes into `result == '405'` which is in the ajax success function. So I think the data is posted. I don't think change the arrow function will cause the error. Have you tried to add breakpoints to debug in IE? Is there any other error in console? I think you can only debug step by step to check every value as I have no idea how you deal with the backend code.

Comment: @YuZhou yeah, '405' is returned when isset($_POST) function in php file is beeing called and it returns '405' if false or proceed further if true. Anyway I did some code in php to checks for user agent and include different js for IE and different js for other browsers. Now it seems to work as i expect.

Comment: That's great! You could post your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou i will :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys - so basically i found a solution which works for me.

I did a simple PHP check if user is using Internet Explorer or any other websites. Depending on the situation - the script is loading JS for Internet Explorer (which actually does not use arrow functions) or JS for other websites (which actually use arrow functions).

```
<?php 

// check user's agent
preg_match('/MSIE (.*?);/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);

if(count($matches)<2){
    preg_match('/Trident\/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}; rv:([0-9]*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
}

if (count($matches)>1){

    // yes, user is using IE => load JS for IE

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript-ie.js"></script>
    <?php

} else {

    // no, user is using web browser other than IE => load default JS

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <?php

} ?>
```